# GIve me short cut for visual studio 2008 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2008, shortcut

In eclipse, F3 or Ctrl+mouseClick in particular on a (function, class, interface, variable) name
opens the corresponding (function, class, interface, variable).
but in visual studio only a same class method definition opens using F12.

What is the corresponding shortcut to Eclipse's F3 / ctrl+click

Comment: Could you rephrase the question?

Answer (score 2):

F12 is *Go To Definition*. It should work regardless of whether the cursor is on a method, type, or field.

Comment: Also, you can use Shift+F12 to go to the declaration for those cases where the declaration and definition aren't the same thing.